# How can solve this equation in $\mathbb N^{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A= \{ \frac{1}{n} / n\in \mathbb N^*\} $ and $B= \{ \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{n} / n\in \mathbb N^*\}$.

Given that $\frac{1}{4} \in (A\cap B)$, I can not to solve in  $\mathbb N^{2}$, the following equation
$$ 3x+3y-xy = 0 .$$
thanks in advance

Comment: How are A and B related to the equation?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin: Let $x \in (A\cap B) $, so $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, so $\exists n,p \in \mathbb N^*$:  $x =\frac{1}{n}$  and $x=\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{p}$, so $x \in (A\cap B) $ returns to $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{p} \Leftrightarrow 3n+3p-np = 0$.

Comment: OK, I got it. Not sure whether it is really helpful in solving the equation, but whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the equation is quite simple if we put it this way:
$$3x = xy-3y$$
$$3x = (x-3)y$$
$$y={3x\over x-3}=3+{9\over x-3}$$
For that to be an integer, $9$ must be divisible by $x-3$, which leaves us with a pretty short list of options.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the equation this way:

$$3x=xy-3y$$
$$\frac1y=\frac13-\frac1x$$
So 1/4 can be on both sides of the equation.